# ASP.NET Core Web API Required Property Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core for my new REST API project. I've add an `ApiExceptionFilter` to get any exception non handle by the system.

But the filter couldn't catch the exception from the [Required] property.
The request will get 400 response with the message.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "XXX": [
            "The XXX field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-fa92d07cf6c8694c87febb276786aada-6f9327722d0cb84b-00"
}
```

I want to customize the error message as the `ApiExcetionFilter` did.
I try to implement `UseExceptionHandler` but didn't get it works.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(c => c.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exception = context.Features
                    .Get<Exception>();

                var response = new { error = exception.Message };
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
            }));
```

Do I have to implement other functions or I did something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, the error is indicating that this is a bad request (response code being 400), rather than an exception. you could create your own custom attribute by extending `ValidationAttribute` and use it in place of the `Required` attribute, and throw the exception from within.

Something like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class RequiredThrowsException : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public RequiredThrowsException(string ErrorMessage = "Some error message here"): base(ErrorMessage) { }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var val = (string)(value);
            if (val is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessage);
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

[This documentation should help with more complex scenarios.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Any exception thrown from within your custom attribute should then be caught by the exception handler.